# How to write js function return innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert emoticon codes into emoticon images. I want to write it within a function. Here is original code without function yet :

```
$.get("showMsgLive.php?username=" + str + "&servertime=" + servertime + "&usertime=" + usertime + "&lastmsgID=" + lastmsgid, function(newitems){
    newitems = newitems.replace(/\(smile1\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/smile1.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(rabbit18\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emospecial/rabbit18.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(rabbit19\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/rabbit19.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(rabbit20\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emoadvance/rabbit20.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(sheep4\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emospecial/sheep4.gif" class="emoticon"/>'); //end of special emo
    newitems.innerHTML = newitems;
    api.getContentPane().append(newitems);
});
```

Here is the code that I try to write it in function :

```
function convertTextEmo(newitems){
    newitems = newitems.replace(/\(smile1\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/smile1.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(rabbit19\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emospecial/rabbit19.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(rabbit20\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emobasic/rabbit20.gif" class="emoticon"/>')
    .replace(/\(sheep4\)/g, '<img src="images/emoticons/emoadvance/sheep4.gif" class="emoticon"/>'); //end of special emo
    return newitems;    
}

jQuery.get("showMsgLive.php?username=" + str + "&servertime=" + servertime + "&usertime=" + usertime + "&lastmsgID=" + lastmsgid, function(newitems){
    convertTextEmo(newitems);
    api.getContentPane().append(newitems);  
});
```

I didn't put `innerHTML` in the function because I don't know where and how to put it, and the output didn't success convert the code into image. May I know where or how to put innerHTML in the function and return the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newitems.innerHTML = newitems;` should not even work as `newitems` is a string and not an HTML element.

I think all you have to do is:

```
api.getContentPane().append(convertTextEmo(newitems));
```

---

Another tip to improve your code: As the image names of are the same as identifiers in the text, you could just create an array of names:

```
var emoticons = ['smile1', 'rabbit18',...];
```

and loop over it:

```
function convertTextEmo(newitems, icons){
    var pattern, content;
    for(var i = icons.length; i--; ) {
        pattern = new RegExp('\(' + icons[i] + '\)', 'g');
        content = '<img src="images/emoticons/emospecial/' + icons[i] + '.gif" class="emoticon"/>';
        newitems = newitems.replace(pattern, content);
    }
    return newitems;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your tip. What value should hold by icons? icons is holding value of emoticons? If so, how to pass value of emoticons into icons?

Comment: You could make `emoticons` global and just call `api.getContentPane().append(convertTextEmo(newitems, emoticons));` I just wanted to provide a general function. You could also access `emoticons` directly from inside `converTextEmo` (if it is global).

Comment: I see. I understood it already. Actually there are 3 groups of emoticons, the 3 categories of emoticons images are saved in 3 different folders - emospecial, emoadvance, emobasic. Regarding your tip, is it possible to check if the emoticons are from which folder? I have updated my question to show you the 3 different folders codes.

Comment: @zac: There are various possibilities. E.g. instead of just saving the name you coud store an array where the second element is the folder name, e.g `[['smile1', 'folder1'], ['rabbit', 'folder2'], ...]`. Or you can make an array of objects: `[{name: 'smile1', folder: 'folder1'], {name: 'rabbit', folder: 'folder2'},...]` or you could create a map `{'rabbit': 'folder1', 'smile': 'folder2'}`...

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.get("showMsgLive.php?username=" + str + "&servertime=" + servertime + "&usertime=" + usertime + "&lastmsgID=" + lastmsgid, function(newitems){
    newitems = convertTextEmo(newitems);
    api.getContentPane().append(newitems);  
});
```

Your function returns the modified HTML.